# What does the point parameter do to Violin plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

What happens when points parameter in `matplotlib`'s  `violinplot` is changed and when would it be useful to do so?

`points` parameter of violin plots is defined as follows.

> points : scalar, default = 100
>
> Defines the number of points to evaluate each of the gaussian kernel density estimations at.

```
Axes.violinplot(self, dataset, positions=None, vert=True, widths=0.5, showmeans=False, showextrema=True, showmedians=False, points=100, bw_method=None, *, data=None)
```

I see very little change on my graphs when I change it. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [official docs] (second emphasis mine)(https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.violinplot.html)

> **points** : scalar, default = 100
>   Defines the number of points **to evaluate each of the gaussian kernel density estimations at.**

So, as the following example (adapted from [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/statistics/violinplot.html)) demonstrates, the effect of number of points is highlighted when chosen a very small number of points. The outcome *of course* also depends on the sample size. Try choosing a smaller sample size like `size=5` and run the same code below. As you increase the points, the smoothness of the density estimation naturally improves. At some cutoff number of points, which is subject to convergence tests, you will see no noticeable impact.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)


fs = 10  # fontsize
pos = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8]
data = [np.random.normal(0, std, size=100) for std in pos]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(10, 3))

axes[0].violinplot(data, pos, points=2, widths=1,
                      showmeans=True, showextrema=True, showmedians=True)
axes[0].set_title('Custom violinplot 1', fontsize=fs)

axes[1].violinplot(data, pos, points=5, widths=1,
                      showmeans=True, showextrema=True, showmedians=True,
                      bw_method='silverman')
axes[1].set_title('Custom violinplot 2', fontsize=fs)

axes[2].violinplot(data, pos, points=100, widths=1,
                      showmeans=True, showextrema=True, showmedians=True,
                      bw_method='silverman')
axes[2].set_title('Custom violinplot 2', fontsize=fs)

for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.set_yticklabels([])

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

**P.S: To highlight the point further,** consider just a single location and three cases: 5, 10 and 50 points as suggested by @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest

```
pos = [1]
data = [np.random.normal(0, std, size=100) for std in pos]
```

[image]

Comment: It's a bit hard to grasp, so maybe something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdQnb.png) would make it easier to see at first sight.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: Thanks for the tip. Updated the answer with something similar